# Custom user-supplied filters, display number of matches for each

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an app where users can track their website visitors in realtime. A user can create Groups, which is basically an array of JSON objects (filters) that they can use to filter a resource (here a website visitor).

```
Group(user_id:id, name:string, filters: JSONB[type, field, value])
```

Example of a group:

```
name: "my group"
filters: [
  {field: "sessions", type: "greater_than", value: 5}, 
  {field: "email", type: "contains", value: "@example.com}
]
```

I am displaying each of a user's groups in the interface, but I'd like to also show the amount of records (visitors) matching each group.

As can be seen, it's possible for website visitors to dynamically be included/excluded in a user's group, depending on their behavior.

I've thought of using a materialized view to keep a mapping of all groups and the count of matches, that'd be updated every 30 seconds. I fear that this will be very inefficeint however.

Is there a better approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the number of records involved, and how much of an impact to your system it will be regenerating the materialized view every 30 seconds. i.e. if the materialized view regenerates in 5 seconds or so, it wouldn't be much of an issue. If it takes 20 seconds while maxing-out processors and disks, then it's a really bad idea.

An alternative is to implement a trigger in your table (or triggers in all involved tables) to increase/decrease counters where appropriate, plus a trigger in your Groups table to calculate the current value whenever a new record is added or the condition is changed.

Comment: The problem with the trigger approach is that a visitor can move to another group without an explicit data change through timestamps as these are just based on how much time has passed